# (chartInit) is not working properly with Karma/Jasmine testing

Tags: angular, karma-runner, echarts

I am having weird issues regarding Angular Testing with a component that uses `echarts`.

In my html I have this div:

```
<div class="jmCanvas">
  <div id="usersLineChart" echarts [options]="optionUsersLineChart" (chartInit)="onChartInitUsersLine($event)" class="demo-chartUsers"></div>
</div>
```

And, in the components I have this part of a code:

```
  onChartInitUsersLine(ec) {
    console.log("setLine");
    this.echartLine = ec;
  }
```

And in the onInit method:

```
console.log(this.echartLine.setOption);
this.echartLine.setOption(this.optionUsersLineChart);
```

Being the `this.optionUsersLineChart`the option file that gets changed according to the model.

This works really well when running normally the application, no problems at all.

But, when running the spec.ts file using:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { UsersViewComponent } from './users-view.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyDateRangePickerModule } from 'mydaterangepicker';
import { NgxEchartsModule, NgxEchartsService } from 'ngx-echarts';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SessionService } from '../Services/session.service';
import { SortingService } from '../sorting.service';
import { testSet } from '../test/testSet';
import { Session } from '../models/Session';

class MockService {
  getSessions(user: string, pageTitle: string, deviceType: string, browser: string, beginDate: number, endDate: number, os: string, screenRes: string,company:string): Observable<any[]> {
    return Observable.of(testSet);
  }      
}

describe('UsersViewComponent', () => {
  let component: UsersViewComponent;
  let service;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UsersViewComponent>;

  function fireEvent(id, event) {
    const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const elem = nativeElement.querySelector('#' + id);
    elem.dispatchEvent(new Event(event));
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MyDateRangePickerModule, NgxEchartsModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [UsersViewComponent]
    }).overrideComponent(UsersViewComponent,{
      set: {
            providers: [
        NgxEchartsService,
        {provide:SessionService,useClass:MockService},
        SortingService
      ]
    }});
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UsersViewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fireEvent("usersLineChart", "chartInit");
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

It fires an error of:

```
TypeError: _this.echartLine.setOption is not a function
```

The event gets fired, according to the console log, but apparently it doesn't find the setOption function in the chart Instance.

Any clue what it might be?

I have tried a number of things and I am stuck with this error for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being an `async` problem. As far I can tell, it was being called the `(chartInit)` after the `onInit()`, thus failling with the given error. I called the `onInit()` manually after the event and It solved the problem.